# Downloading specific files(regex specific files) from FTP folder using java

Tags: java, ftp

I am  trying to download files from FTP folder using java but I want to download certain files not all the files. How to add the regex to the code to download the files.

right now I am able to download all the files from FTP location. I want to add regex so it downloads specific files.

```
private static void downloadFolder(
    FTPClient ftpClient, String remotePath, String localPath) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Downloading folder " + remotePath + " to " + localPath);

    FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(remotePath);

    for (FTPFile remoteFile : remoteFiles)
    {
        if (!remoteFile.getName().equals(".") && !remoteFile.getName().equals(".."))
        {
            String remoteFilePath = remotePath + "/" + remoteFile.getName();
            String localFilePath = localPath + "/" + remoteFile.getName();

            if (remoteFile.isDirectory())
            {
                new File(localFilePath).mkdirs();

                downloadFolder(ftpClient, remoteFilePath, localFilePath);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Downloading file " + remoteFilePath + " to " +
                    localFilePath);

                OutputStream outputStream =
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFilePath));
                if (!ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, outputStream))
                {
                    System.out.println("Failed to download file " + remoteFilePath);
                }
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: filter the list? what's the problem _exactly_, don't see you trying _anything_. ..

Answer (score 1):

`listFiles` is overloaded to accept an optional `FTPFileFilter`. This is an interface with a single method, so you can use a lambda for the implementation. For instance:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("whatever you need");
FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(remotePath,
        file -> pattern.matcher(file.getName()).matches());
```

Comment: Did you mean `pattern.matcher(file.getName()).matches()`?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I switched from a block implementation to an expression and something got mixed up. I've fixed it.